# How can I find methods without an explicit access modifier?

Tags: .net, coding-style, fxcop, stylecop

I am using FxCop and I would like to find all the methods or variables without an access modifier explicitly defined. For example:

```
class MyClass
{
   int myInt = 0;

   internal MyClass()
   {
   }
}
```

I would like FxCop to warn me that I didn't specify what access modifier will be applied to the variable "myInt" or the class "MyClass". Has anyone done this before, or can anyone offer guidance on where to start?

**Update:** Just to let everyone know, the StyleCop rule that looks for this is **SA1400**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FxCop analyses the compiled code, which has access modifiers applied. You need to use a tool like [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) to detect coding syntax issues such as not explicitly declaring access modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Using FxCop I beleive the only way to do this would be to write your own custom rule. This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2004/01/09/writing-custom-rules-in-fxcop-amp-fxcop-visual-studio-integration-jeffrey-van-gogh.aspx) is a good place to start.

You may also want to take a look at [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis) and [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/). I'm almost certain NDepend will do this (although you may have to write some custom CQL) and I know StyleCop will do this out of the box.

Comment: FxCop can't detect coding semantics like this as the access modifier is applied during compilation.